# Pandoc citations in the footnote

Tags: citing, footnotes, pandoc, markdown, pandoc-citeproc

I am using Pandoc for writing texts with Latex or Markdown and converting them to Word (because of no reason everyone else still wants this word-shit).
Now I have to convert my citations into footnote style.
I have found the filter mode `notes-after-punctuation` but don't know how I should implement this into my call, e.g. from Rmd to doc:

`pandoc -f markdown -t docx --reference-doc=JJL.dotx --resource-path=.:figures  --filter pandoc-crossref --filter pandoc-citeproc  --bibliography=sample.bib -o output.docx doc.Rmd`

Manipulation the output of the citations via Latex didn't work with the following:

```
\usepackage[style=footnote-dw, 
natbib=true, 
backref=true, 
edsuper=true, 
nopublisher=false, 
urldate=long, 
backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Comment: With biblatex, you have the `\footcite` command, if I understand well your problem.

Comment: yes, that could be a solution, but only for latex not for markdown

Comment: It was of course just a suggestion, as I don't know markdown. Another suggestion: can you use the `footbib` package?

Comment: also, \footfullcite wouldn't work here. Bit thanks for the idea!

Comment: You can only use bib(la)tex if the output format is latex and you have to use `--bibtex` or `--biblatex` instead of `pandoc-citeproc`. If you are using `pandoc-citeproc`, which is needed for .docx, then you have to find a suitable CSL style that matches your requirements. You can access a huge database of available styles here: [Zotero Style Repository](https://www.zotero.org/styles). Filter for format `note`

Comment: Thank you! this Zotero Style is a great repository!

Comment: yes, you can do that. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DG' writes one can load a citation style from a csl-file from the [Zotero Style Repository](https://www.zotero.org/styles). The code would be like:

```
pandoc -f latex -t docx --bibliography=sample.bib --csl journal-of-linguistics.csl  -o output.docx text.tex
```